# Water wheel physics/math model

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I have the following water wheel,and I have to model this wheel. I've googled it and found two different models, which one should I use or is there someone that can find a better model that fits my water wheel?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The water comes from the top side over the wheel so it will spin. Thanks for any help.

My two hits:

1. http://www.reed.edu/physics/faculty/illing/campus/pdf/RachelThesis09.pdf
2. https://workspace.imperial.ac.uk/physicsuglabs/public/3rd_Year_Projects/3rd%20yr%20proj_waterwheel_amjphys.pdf

Comment: And the second one https://workspace.imperial.ac.uk/physicsuglabs/public/3rd_Year_Projects/3rd%20yr%20proj_waterwheel_amjphys.pdf

Comment: What do you want the model to be able to do for you? In other words - what inputs and outputs do you expect; and what accuracy?

Comment: @Floris Inputs as much as possible (that are relevant) and output the power and torque that the wheel generates

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) Please note that this is neither about mathematical physics nor about the standard model. Furtheron, this might be suited for the engineering SE too.

Comment: @Sanya It is because I've to use Physics and math to model this system

Comment: The first hit is for a very different kind of waterwheel (a chaotic wheel) which is not at all what you want...

Comment: @Floris I see, but the other one does not show the outputs that I'm looking for, I think

Comment: @Klaas that does not mean you should tag your question as a question about quantum field theories or the mathematical structure/foundaton of physical theories - which you have done.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the models you found is appropriate. And since this sounds like a educational assignment, I think it's better that you develop your own model.

I suggest you make a cross sectional model of the waterwheel. You will see that the amount of water that fits in a "cup" is a function of the angle of the cup relative to the axis. For simplicity, assume that the cup is "filled to the brim" - and as it goes lower, water will pour out. Write down a simple function of "water in each container as a function of angular position".

Once you have an expression for the volume of water in each compartment as a function of angle, you can calculate the contribution to torque: for this, you take the component of gravitational force on each cup, and multiply it by the horizontal distance.

Finally - to get power, you need to know how fast the wheel is turning. If the wheel is moving quite slowly, the water flow at the top will be sufficient to keep the compartments fully filled, and power will be torque multiplied by angular velocity. But once the amount of water available per unit time is less than is needed to fill your containers completely, you will see two new things happen:

1. Since the container starts out "less than full", it will turn further before water tips out
2. The torque generated will be less because the containers are not full.

These two things mean that there is an upper limit to the power that can be extracted with this wheel. The limit will be less than the power you could get from the flow rate of the water multiplied by the height of the wheel (that is the theoretical amount of power to be obtained).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is for a project that I'm working on. Can you help me with setting up those equations?